# Kubernetes no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to deploy the next frontend-deployment.yaml in Kubernetes using Jenkins, but I am having the next error:

```
[frontend] Running shell script
+ kubectl apply -f IKonnekt/frontend-deployment.yaml
error: unable to recognize "IKonnekt/frontend-deployment.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
```

If I run `kubectl apply -f IKonnekt/frontend-deployment.yaml` from a machine inside the Kubernetes cluster it works fine.

```
Kubernetes Client Version: 1.12.1
Kubernetes Server Version: 1.11.0
```

This is my frontend-deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ikonnekt-frontend-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ikonnekt-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ikonnekt-frontend
        image: ikonnektfrontend
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: REACT_APP_API
          value: "http://IP:Port"
        - name: REACT_APP_AUTH_ENDPOINT
          value: "http://IP:Port/auth"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

Comment: Looks odd: `extensions/v1beta1` should still be in 1.11 what's the `kubectl` version in Jenkins?

Comment: Rico absolutely right :) check installed kubectl version in Jenkins

Comment: @Rico The kubectl client version of Jenkins is 1.12.1. Is the same as the nodes in the cluster. And nodes in cluster can deploy correctly, but with the Jenkins node it fails.

Comment: @DenisA. Jenkins kubectl client version is 1.12.1.

Comment: Finally it worked for me... the problem was that in the Jenkinsfile I was using the dashboard URL instead of the kubernetes api URL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem was because in the Jenkinsfile I was using the Kubernetes dashboard URL instead of the Kubernetes API URL, so the kubectl of Jenkins couldn't recognize the kubernetes server.

So finally, using the API URL and updating the apiVersion it works for me.

Answer (score 20):

Just change **apiVersion** to  this: `apiVersion: apps/v1`

Comment: Still doesn't work, the solution was to use ```apps/v1beta1```!

Comment: Works on kubernetes `1.17.0`

Comment: I am stuck here, and neither "extensions" works nor "apps"