# Error applying "deployment.yaml" using kubectl in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, kubectl

I'm trying to apply following deployment.yaml using Jenkins and it gave me error saying,

```
error: unable to recognize "deployment.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
```

But when I do the same thing using directly inside the linux server, it got succeeded.

kubectl version :

```
    Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.8-eks-cd3eb0", GitCommit:"cd3eb06a896644a770b14acf6b3123b417fa50e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-07-31T00:59:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12+", GitVersion:"v1.12.10-eks-825e5d", GitCommit:"825e5de08cb05714f9b224cd6c47d9514df1d1a7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-18T03:58:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Deployemnt.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
      name: {{APP_NAME}}
  name: {{APP_NAME}}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: {{APP_NAME}}
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: {{APP_NAME}}
        run: {{APP_NAME}}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{APP_NAME}}
        image: xxxxxxxxxxx.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx:{{IMAGE_ID}}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Please try to change apiVersion from `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1` to  `apiVersion: apps/v1` or `apiVersion: apps/v1beta1`, let me know if that help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52877751/kubernetes-no-matches-for-kind-deployment-in-version-extensions-v1beta1)

Comment: @jt97I tried the methods you shared, but same issue I'm getting, 
error: unable to recognize "deployment.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1beta1

Comment: Please provide informations about api-versions on your cluster, you can use  `kubectl api-versions`.

Comment: @jt97I got the following result for kubectl api-versions, and result is too long to display, but some of this result goes here.....admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
apps/v1
apps/v1beta1
apps/v1beta2
authentication.k8s.io/v1
authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
authorization.k8s.io/v1
authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
autoscaling/v1
autoscaling/v2beta1
autoscaling/v2beta2
batch/v1
batch/v1beta1
certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
coordination.k8s.io/v1beta1
crd.k8s.amazonaws.com/v1alpha1